# Create another model upon Devise User registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to create a Profile model upon my Users registering for the site. As I have it now the Profile model is being created upon registration with the correct foreign key. My problem lies with trying to update the Profile model after the user has gone through the Devise confirmation steps.

My users are called "artists".

```
### /artists/registrations_controller.rb ###

class Artists::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
    @profile = @artist.build_artist_profile
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
    @profile = @artist.create_artist_profile(profile_params)
  end

 private

  def profile_params
    params.permit(:biography, :location, :genre, :members, :facebook_url, :twitter_url, :youtube_url, :itunes_url, :amazon_url)
  end

end

### /artists/profiles_controller ###

class Artists::ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_artist!
  before_action :correct_artist
  before_action :set_artist

  def edit
    @profile = ArtistProfile.find_by(params[:artist_id])
  end

  def update
    @profile = ArtistProfile.find_by(params[:artist_id])
    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
      redirect_to current_artist
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  private

    def set_artist
      @artist = current_artist
    end

    def correct_artist
      @artist = current_artist
      if @artist != Artist.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to artist_path
      end
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:artist_profile).permit(:biography, :location, :genre, :members, :facebook_url, :twitter_url, :youtube_url, :itunes_url, :amazon_url)
    end

end

### /artist.rb ###

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
  has_one :artist_profile, dependent: :destroy

### /artist_profile.rb ###

class ArtistProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  validates :artist_id, presence: true
end
```

I put my own code into the Devise registration controller in the create method. Upon registration the ArtistProfile model is created and populated with blank strings, which is prefect. However, if I try to edit/update the individual artist's profile only the very first artist's profile gets updated.

ie. Artist 1 signs up and profile 2 is created. Artist 1 updates Profiles 1's location to Buffalo via the edit page. Artist 2 signs up and Profile 2 is created. Artist 2 updates Profile 2's location to New York, but Profile 1's location is updated, not Profile 2's.

Is this the way to create a model upon registration, and if so, how do I fix the edit/update methods?

Or is there a better way altogether?

Comment: why are you using `find_by(params[artist_id])` aren't you looking up a ArtistProfile not an artist?

Comment: Right, but doesn't that find the ArtistProfile by the artist's id? I've tried it using artist_id and just id and both produce the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of your code is incorrect:

```
@profile = ArtistProfile.find_by(params[:artist_id])
```

A fix is to find the artist, then get the profile:

```
@profile = Artist.find(params[:artist_id]).artist_profile
```

An optimization:

```
@artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id]).includes(:artist_profile)
@profile = @artist.artist_profile
```

Or, if your controller is receiving the artist profile id, then you can do this fix:

```
@profile = ArtistProfile.find(params[:artist_profile_id])
```

Comment: Thank you! Here's the what worked for me: Since `@artist` is set the the `current_artist` via the `set_artist` method I left it alone, but I changed the `@profile = ArtistProfile.find_by(params[:artist_id])` to `@profile = @artist.artist_profile` and it seemed to do the trick!